# Riddle: In an improved ocean

Tags: riddle, word, computer-science

In an improved ocean, its results are faster and bigger than the results of changeling courses.

In coffee, it is actually nondescript, and after proofreading, it pretty much amounts to destroying and tossing the copy.

In half a swimmer's surname, it could help a spider with mass production, and with keeping problems distinct.

With something mistakenly named a successor, you might think it's plotting against you.

What is it?

Comment: I edited and undeleted my answer. Apologies for the earlier mis-performance.

Comment: FYI, in case you don't notice the edit, I converted my partial answer to a complete attempt...

Comment: should there be a comma after `and after proofreading,` ?

Comment: @Maslow Sure, I guess that could make it a bit clearer grammatically.

Comment: I just edited to accept Maslow's edit suggestion, and also to add a couple new tags now that the answer is pretty much known (though the justifications still need some work).

Comment: A hint on line 4: One of the things it can commonly do in this context is help in setting up tables.  The term some "restaurants" use for groupings of tables is the relation to "plotting against you"; and the same term more generally can also refer to the "shapes" of the tables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> [Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) (i.e. the use of generic programming in software development to avoid code duplication).

Each of the four lines relates to

> how templates (or their rough equivalents) are used in different programming languages:
>
> 1. The first line is referring to **C++** ("*improved ocean*" => sea plus => C++), where templates provide generic support. From @MOehm in the comments, C++ templates "will generate code for every instantiated type, so it's more optimized, but requires more memory but result in more memory consumption", which is what is alluded to by "*results are faster and bigger than the results of changeling courses*". Here, "*changeling courses*" refer to "polymorphic classes" (via inheritance), which would be one of the common alternatives to templating.
> 2. The second line refers to **Java** ("*coffee*" => (synonymous with) => Java), where their implementation is called generics (which is certainly "*nondescript*"), and is provided as pure syntactic sugar, which is not available at runtime. In other words, after compilation ("*after proofreading*") the type erasure ("*destroying*") results in byte code that is the equivalent of not using generics and just casting the relevant types ("*tossing the copy*").
> 3. The third line is about **PHP** ("*half a swimmer's surname*" => PHelPs => PHP), which is a language used predominantly to template web pages ("*spider with mass production*"), and as with any templating, it assists in enforcing a separation of concerns, by "*keeping problems distinct*".
> 4. The fourth line is referring to **SQL** ("*successor*" => sequel => SQL), which doesn't have templates per se, but allows similar meta/generic programming via the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (and a schema/schemer is certainly something that might be "*plotting against you*").

Comment: This might be a coincidence, but there's a programming language named CoffeeScript that compiles into Javascript code. CoffeeScript's goal is to create a more elegant and fun way to type Javascript. Perhaps it means the process of its compilation, *Reading* the code and interpreting, compiling the CoffeeScript code into Javascript code and ignoring the *copy* AKA the CoffeeScript code.

Comment: @IIRawCodeII - I considered that, but figured Java fit better with the other two. Also, your remarks about trans/compiling the code itself (as opposed to a specific single code feature), could equally be applied to Java.

Comment: On the fourth line, successor might be referring to a sequel. If you get what I mean.

Comment: @RickvanOsta - Good spotting. That makes sense. Will update my answer...

Comment: All of these except Java have templates, which fits the C++ and PHP lines. (I don't know enough about SQL to see how SQL server script templates plot against you.)

Comment: @MOehm - yeah, I thought about templates as the answer, but it doesn't feel super satisfying (Java's closest equivalent is probably generics, which is implemented as pure syntax sugar if memory serves so that kind of fits my notes, but I'm not aware of any templating in SQL, and I'm not quite sure how it relates to the first line either). My other guess was 'optimisation', or similar, which fits my first and last notes, buy again isn't exactly satisfying...

Comment: In C++, a template will generate code for every instantiated type, so it's more optimized, but requires more memory. I think that and PHP templates are a good fit, but I'm not so convinced about the others. The thing about Java generics is that they _aren't_ templates.

Comment: @MOehm agreed that they aren't strictly templates, but as I said they are kind of similar-ish, and now that I'm writing this I also note that "nondescript" => generic...

Comment: @MOehm - also (knowing nothing of the language), I note that Wikipedia says "Scheme syntactic abstractions also have a connection to genericity – these are in fact a superset of templating à la C++", which fits nicely with line 4 (successor + plotting)...

Comment: Yes, the intended answer was "templates" - with #2 being that Java generics could informally be called templates, especially by programmers with a C++ background due to the similar syntax and similarity in usage.  (Sorry if that turns out to only be the case in my neck of the woods...)

Comment: But the justification on #4 is not what I was thinking of...  Rock van Osta was on the right track here.

Comment: On line 3, I was thinking of a specific programming term relating to the phrase "keeping problems distinct"...

Comment: On line 2, "destroying... copy" was specifically referring to the mechanism of "type erasure" (with "copy" = "type" = "what is being edited or published").  Now, what might "tossing copy" be referring to?

Comment: And similarly, on line 2, "proofreading" was a paraphrase of a specific compiler-related term.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - made some updates/corrections based on your comments if you want to take a look...

Comment: Actually, I've seen "SQL templating" refer to a mechanism to have an SQL script with parameters that are filled in at execution time.  Either as a specific feature of the MS SQL server, or as a feature of wrapper libraries around SQL.  And my understanding of the term "schema" was, as I said, either a term used by many SQL implementations to refer to a grouping of tables, or more generally a "database schema" refers to the layout of a database, i.e. the names of tables and the types of data in each column of the tables.

Comment: And I guess on the last small piece in line 2, I'll just come out and say it: "proofreading" was an oblique reference to "type checking" - as I understand it, the main advantage of generics is that it helps the compiler with doing type checking, versus the situation pre Java 5 where code would just do the typecasting of `Object` results to the specific type itself without much type safety.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - I've not come across the type of SQL templating you refer to, so I was assuming the need for something more hand-crafted, hence the need for accessing the schema info. Was that not your intention of the "plotting" clue? ...either way, given we're down into the minutiae, feel free to directly edit in anything I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

> I think that the answer by @Alconja is on the right track *for the first part* of each clue. I will mark what else I think needs to be de-cryptified `like this`

---

> In *C++*, its results are faster and bigger than the results of `changeling courses`.

---

> In *Java*, it is actually nondescript, and after proofreading it pretty much amounts to destroying and tossing the copy.

---

> In *PHP*, it could help a spider with mass production, and with keeping problems distinct.

---

> With *SQL*, you might think it's plotting against you.

---

> So, I do not know what `changeling courses` is but think that otherwise, it is a comparison as it is written. The results spoken of would seem to be the results of compiling the code. I haven't much experience with Java but, nondescript is "lacking distinctive or interesting features or characteristics" and "Java source code is compiled into bytecode when we use the javac compiler" which pretty much fits that description but, I cannot relate the second part of that clue except that bytecode does not resemble the original code... Cancel that, I think I have an answer after re-reading the fourth clue.

---

> I am going to guess that the answer is `executable code`.

---

> The first clue describes C++ executable code. The second clue describes Jave executable code. The third clue describes PHP executable code. The fourth clue describes executable code problems for SQL.

Comment: Too many guesses?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! To explain the downvotes you're getting: it's not so much that you're posting multiple guesses at once (I don't know what the community consensus is on that), but that you haven't *explained* any of them. You should explain how each of your answers fits the riddle, otherwise they're not considered answers.

Comment: Ahh. Okay, I guess I need to do more writing then and explain.

Comment: @F1Krazy Actually, is it against the rules if I have to justify everything to burn it and make it a work in progress?

Comment: You're perfectly allowed to delete your answer, add in your explanations, and then undelete it once you've finished.

Answer (score 1):

Based only on the very first hint

> which realtes to c++ == sea plus plus == improved ocean (thanks @Alconja)

I would say that the solution is

> templates

since it is opposed to

> `changeling courses` == polymorphism, and the results of using templates rather than virtual calls gets you a bigger executable which is faster by avoiding virtual calls...

but, I have no idea how to fit the other hints, as

> I do not know almost anything about the other "languages"

Comment: This guess is the correct answer.  (Actually, for "changeling courses" I was thinking specifically of "polymorphic classes".)  Alconja's answer currently has correct explanations for lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Also, on a technical note, the speed improvement from templates is not just avoiding virtual calls, but also the fact that the optimizer can work individually on each template instantiation - and also can often inline the template instantiations and then apply further optimizations..

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> Injection

It fits the second and fourth lines

> 2. Dependency Injection (syntactic sugar) 
>  4. SQL injection (you might think it's plotting against you)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be

> virtual

improved ocean

> Refers to C++ that uses virtual methods.

Coffee

> The Java Virtual Machine usually uses much of its resources to destroy temporary objects.

Half a swimmer

> PHP can be modularized using Virtual() to load other code files.

Successor

> Don't know how this fits into my answer